# SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when trying to install packages using pip - behind corporate proxy

Tags: python, windows, ssl, pip

Ive already tried doing pip install --proxy DOMAIN\username:password@proxyserver:port packagename and the pip.ini thing, also doing --trusted host.

Is there any other way for me to install pip packages behind a proxy?

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out i struggled for no reason at all.
All i had to do was:

```
set https_proxy=http://login:password@address:port
```

Answer (score 0):

At times, the **wrong version number** SSL error when running **Pip**, **Curl** or **Wget** commands is caused by incorrect corporate forward proxy settings.

On Linux, ensure that your  `https_proxy` variable in `/etc/environment` file is not set to use the `https` protocol for the proxy server address, instead of `http`.

We experience the SSL error when our work computer had a proxy environmental variable that was set as `https_proxy=https://address:port` instead of `https_proxy=http://address:port`.